# The run time is too long

Tags: python

**When I test it with code, there is no error, but it fails with a timeout.**

**Problem**

The failure rate is defined as follows.
Number of players / number of players as far as stage is concerned
The total number N of stages, the game can be currently stopped by the user. .

**Limitations**

The number N of stages is a natural number of 1 or more and 500 or less.
The length of the stage is 1 or more and 200,000 or less.
Contains natural water above step 1 and below N + 1.
Each natural number is currently being challenged by the user.
N + 1 is the final stage.
There is still a failure rate.
The success rate of the stage is zero.

**My code**

```
def solution(N, stages):
    fail = []
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        no_clear = stages.count(i)
        he_stage = sum([stages.count(x) for x in range(i,N+2)])
        if no_clear==0: 
            fail.append((i,0))
        else: 
            fail.append((i,no_clear/he_stage))
    fail=sorted(fail,key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
    print(fail)
    return [fail[i][0] for i in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `stages` is a `list`. Calling `count` repeatedly on a `list` has a very high complexity, specially if you're doing that in a loop.

You could use a cache or maybe simpler: replace `stages.count(x)` by a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object call

before:

```
def solution(N, stages):
    fail = []
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        no_clear = stages.count(i)
        he_stage = sum([stages.count(x) for x in range(i,N+2)])
```

after:

```
import collections
def solution(N, stages):
   fail = []
   stages_counter = collections.Counter(stages)
   for i in range(1,N+1):
       no_clear = stages_counter[i]
       he_stage = sum(stages_counter[x] for x in range(i,N+2))
```

This will reduce your complexity a great deal. Elements are counted once and for all. Just access the dictionary in `O(1)` time once it's done.

Comment: Thank you so much.There was a lack of explanation, thank you very much for your sincere answer !!!  
The problem is solved.